# What is the word that means there is a difference in import of the same words when the exact same words are spoken by a different person

Tags: single-word-requests

I have come across this word in a book; it gives the example:

> If a layman says “I now pronounce you man and wife,” it doesn't make
>   the couple husband and wife.
>
> But when the same words are spoken by a priest, it makes them husband
>   and wife.

The word possibly starts with either "i" or "l".

Comment: They're [performative verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416216/could-you-clarify-performative-verbs-can-the-utterance-i-run-be-grammatical) (this question might be a dup of the one I linked to there). The only reason it makes a difference whether a priest or a layman speaks your cited example is because some people wouldn't recognise the *authority* of anyone except a priest to marry people. But anyone could say *I promise [something]*, in which case the act of saying it is the same thing as the act of promising itself.

Comment: The word you are thinking of  may be _illocutionary_, one of the _speech acts_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act#Illocutionary_acts

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is the word I am looking for. I love the forum :)

Comment: In my opinion the example sentence "I now pronounce you man and wife" has the same *meaning* regardless of who says it, but it has a different *effect* depending on whether the speaker is legally empowered to conduct weddings.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes; we have to be precise hereabouts. I've edited, but retained some fuzziness with 'import' which can mean either 'how the quote can be defined (I'm avoiding 'meaning')' or 'what the consequences of delivering the quote are'. The problems surrounding the whole concept of 'performative verbs' are discussed in the threads [Please clarify 'performative verbs'_can the utterance 'I run' be grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416216/could-you-clarify-performative-verbs-can-the-utterance-i-run-be-grammatical) and  ...

Comment: ['performative utterance_illocutionary act'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64420/conversational-postulate/64434#64434). Where spoken words (like handshakes and signatures) are seen to confer change in status (weddedness, change of ownership ...) authority (together with the legal framework) is the key issue. With 'creative words', power is another key issue. The supernatural complicates things.

Comment: Perhaps "incumbent" fits - as an example - "The actual incumbent effect is totally dependent upon the speaker's qualifications.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to a comment posted by [Shoe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459977/what-is-the-word-that-means-there-is-a-difference-in-import-of-the-same-words-wh/524466#comment1108706_459977) and a comment posted by [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/459977/what-is-the-word-that-means-there-is-a-difference-in-import-of-the-same-words-wh#comment1239798_459977), the phrase you are looking for is [Illocutionary acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_act#Illocutionary_acts).

This was defined by John L. Austin as follows:

> I explained the performance of an act in this new and second sense as the performance of an '*illocutionary*' act, i.e. the performance of an act *in* saying something as opposed to the performance of an act *of* saying something — J. L. Austin, ed. J. O. Ursom, *How to Do Things with Words*, 2011, Clarendon Press, Oxford.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the priest saying the words, the priest is **empowered** to give them special weight and significance.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*empower*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empower):

> **1** : to give official authority or legal power to
> // *empowered* her attorney to act on her behalf

So:

> The priest *empowered* the words "I now pronounce you husband and wife."
> The priest was *empowered* to make the everyday phrase spiritually and legally binding.

---

Alternatively, if it really is a word that has to start with *i*, then the priest **imbues** the words with special significance.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*imbue*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imbue):

> **1** : ENDOW sense 3
> // Spanish missions *imbue* the city with Old World charm
> — Scott Pendleton
>
> *Endow* sense 3
> : to provide with something freely or naturally
> // *endowed* with a good sense of humor

Answer (score 0):

## Authoritative

-Commanding and self-confident; likely to be respected and obeyed.
‘his voice was calm and authoritative’

-Proceeding from an official source and requiring compliance or obedience.
‘authoritative directives’

*from Lexico.com, the free Oxford English Dictionary
https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/authoritative*